# how to add index to column with duplicate values to make the query faster in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Here's the table in Postgresql:

```
name, ts, value
A, 2017-05-28, 1
A, 2017-05-27, 5
A, 2017-05-26, 2
...
B, 2017-05-28, 9
B, 2017-05-28, 12
...
```

The size of the table will be over 10 million. I'm trying to execute `select count(distinct(name)) from "table";` and it takes me over 240s without ending. Could anyone give some suggestions regarding the way to optimise this scenario, like adding partition like Hive or adding index (which needs to be unique, but the name is duplicate across multiple records). Thanks!

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Postgres does not optimize `count(distinct name)` very well.  (Intriguingly, Hive -- which has a very different optimizer -- has a similar problem.)

Try running the query this way:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct name
      from t
     ) t;
```

I don't think an index will help, but you can always try using one on `t(name)`.